# MySQL loose comparison on INT fields

Tags: php, mysql

I recently saw something in MySQL which I consider odd, however, I am unsure if it is MySQL doing this or PHP.

Basically I have this query using the PDO library:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id OR email=:id
```

Using the bound parameter of `xxx@gmail.com` as `:id`. It is able to find the record where `email` is `NULL` and `id` is `0`. After some investigation I found out that this was because there was some lose casting being done that meant `xxx@gmail.com` was being casted as `0` (like in PHP) to compare with `id`. The `id` field is `INT`.

Is this MySQL or PHP? Is there a way to stop loose casting and comparisons from happening in MySQL using the PHP PDO driver?

If it matters my table is MyISAM.

#### Edit

The exact code being used is:

```
$result = database::getInstance()->query("
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE partner_id = :id OR email = :id LIMIT 1",
    array(':id'=>$id)
);
```

Whereby `database` is a singleton instance which routes queries to the PDO library. It does no alteration to the query except run it for me. I know this part works since it is unit tested and it works with every other query in the application, this is the only malfunctioning query.

And the code within the query function:

```
        if($params===array()){
            $command=$this->_connection->prepare($sql);
        }else{
            $paramCount=0;

            // Then arguments have been supplied
            foreach($params as $field => $param){
                if(is_array($param)){
                    $values = $params[$field];
                    unset($params[$field]);

                    $fparams=array();
                    foreach($values as $value){
                        $fparams[]=$this->paramPrefix.$paramCount;
                        $params[$this->paramPrefix.$paramCount++]=$value;
                    }
                    $sql=str_replace($field,'('.implode(', ',$fparams).')',$sql);
                }
            }
            $command=$this->_connection->prepare($sql);
        }

        $command->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($params as $field=>$param)
            $command->bindValue($field,$param);
        $command->execute();
        return $command;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `SELECT 'string' = 0;` and that should answer your question.

(For further reference: it returns `1`)

Comment: Is there a way to stop that? Or is this actually a quirk in SQL that it thinks those two are objectively equal?

Comment: By SQL I mean MySQL of course, since this is probably to do with MySQLs programming more than SQL standard itself

Comment: This is MySQL specific as far as I can tell. Other DBMSs behave differently (from throwing errors, to returning 0) You might want to look into server modes to see if it can be switched off: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html . As you said, SQL standard does not specify how such comparison should be done. The best way to proceed would be to make sure you have a number in your variable, before you put it into the query.

Comment: Ok Kool thanks for the help :) gonna leave this open a sec to see if anyone else has a nugget

Comment: @Sammaye yes I know a way to stop it. just use quotations for checking strings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this. note the (string) cast if this works, PDO is using some type checking and recast in the function bindValue

```
$result = database::getInstance()->query("
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE partner_id = :id OR email = :id LIMIT 1",
    array(':id'=>((string)$id))
);
```

Comment: As proven by Mchl's answer this is happening within MySQL itself, no matter how I type cast the `$id` (it is actually already a string) it will not matter because to MySQL `'string'=0`